# Where can I find the PhoneGap/Cordova executable installed by Meteor for the WebStorm plugin?

Tags: cordova, meteor, webstorm

I use WebStorm 9 EAP for Meteor 0.9.4-pre.11 development and would like to use the PhoneGap/Cordova plugin by WebStorm, but I can't find the executable for PhoneGap/Cordova that Meteor must have installed somewhere.

Does anybody know where Meteor installs this to and if the plugin can be used with Meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/<TOOL VERSION>/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin`

`<TOOL VERSION>` is changing from release to release.

Comment: Excellent, but on Ubuntu (14.04) I had to remove the leading `/` to get it to work, being `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/[...]` then.