# WebStorm Cordova executable invalid

Tags: cordova, meteor, webstorm

I am trying to set up WebStorm to use the executable of Cordova that comes with Meteor. I set the executable path in Settings/Languages & Frameworks/Javascript/PhoneGap/Cordova to 
`/home/jonfor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova.cmd`

I get an error "Please correct path to PhoneGap/Cordova executable".

I'm not sure why WebStorm doesn't recognize cordova.cmd, unless the Cordova executable that comes with Meteor is different than the one I would get from NPM or this is a bug. Any ideas?

I am running WebStorm 10.0.4 on Linux Mint 17. I found the path for the Cordova executable from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222123/where-can-i-find-the-phonegap-cordova-executable-installed-by-meteor-for-the-web) and followed the JetBrains official set-up instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-phonegap-cordova.html#d207895e252).

Comment: `cordova.cmd` sounds like name for Windows ... while you are on Linux. Do you have file named just `cordova` in that folder? if you do -- try it instead.

Comment: Yes there is. That does not work either. For some reason it is marked as a Javascript file. I checked in WebStorms's File Types menu and checked under JavaScript and ECMAScript 6. There isn't any messed up pattern that marks extension-less files as .js.

Comment: *"There isn't any messed up pattern that marks extension-less files as .js."* How does that file looks like (first line or two) -- does it has shebang (e.g. something like `#!/bin/node`). If does -- then it's all good (I mean -- file association -- autodetection is in place). *"That does not work either."* No clues then...

Comment: The first line is  `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Perhaps I should report this as a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: *"The first line is `#!/usr/bin/env node`"* This line is fine .. so association with JS inside IDE is correct. Don't know about the rest, sorry (I'm a Windows user so do not know what exactly should be used there on Linux/Mac).

Comment: do you have error message for path /home/jonfor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova ? It works fine for me

Comment: Yup, It says the same message: "Please correct path to PhoneGap/Cordova executable".

Comment: Did yout fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I change executable path to cordova to /usr/local/bin/cordova. Try this, it should be help.